# Homebrew: Terminal Emoticons How?

Tags: bash, homebrew, iterm

I use [homebrew](https://brew.sh/) for package management on my mac. Today after updating homebrew I saw something I've never seen before;

[image: Homebrew screenshot in iTerm]

There was a tiny beer emoticon in the terminal. How is this being done!? What kinds of terminals is this supported in? I'm using iTerm 2 for my terminal.

Related: https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/issues/17085

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yikes! iTerm says it was fixed in a build on 01/20. But I believe the beer mug is a branding point. Maybe just update.

http://code.google.com/p/iterm2/issues/detail?id=2279&sort=-id

ITerm Patch for emoji: http://code.google.com/p/iterm2/issues/detail?id=2062#c5

How its done? It is just Apple. The glyph substitution algorithm is picking up the text and replacing it with emoji (which is ttf on mac) – Benjiman 50 secs ago edit

Comment: No, my iTerm doesn't crash, I was just wondering how they are showing these icons. I actually updated iTerm yesterday btw.

Comment: Oh, sorry. It is just Apple. The glyph substitution algorithm is picking up the text and replacing it with emoji (which is ttf on mac)

Comment: Unicode codepoint U+1F37A (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emoji) 